# MySQL Foreign Key ERROR. Constraint key error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I can't add a foreign key to an existing table. The error is as follows

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `sms`.`student_account` 
ADD INDEX `student_id_idx` (`student_id` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
ALTER TABLE `sms`.`student_account` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `student_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`)
  REFERENCES `sms`.`student` (`student_id`)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `sms`.`student_account` 
ADD INDEX `student_id_idx` (`student_id` ASC) VISIBLE
```

Comment: why do you tag sqlite if it's mysql?

Comment: The ; in your fouth line must be removed.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I tried to remove it but still it does not work.

Comment: Here on the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=6a55c13a2c2177960d1f1df4d4939bcc) everything executes fine. Can you try to setup it in a way to reproduce your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written the schema below which is working. I advise against using the same name `student_id` for the constraint as already used for the column. I would prefer `fk_student_id` to avoid risk of an ambiguity or conflict at some point.

> ```
> create table `student_account` (
>   student_id int);
> create table  `student`(
>   student_id int primary key
>   );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE `student_account` 
> ADD INDEX `student_id_idx` (`student_id` ASC) VISIBLE;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE `student_account` 
> ADD CONSTRAINT `student_id`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`)
>   REFERENCES `student` (`student_id`)
>   ON DELETE RESTRICT
>   ON UPDATE CASCADE;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bcedaa2d23d65b9516817867760a6155)*